# JQuery help Adding text in a dialog box

Tags: jquery

I've been looking for an answer for quite a few hours now but with no luck.
I got a dialog box that pop to ask user email, I simply want to add an extra line of text to it, between the text area where the user input his email and the OK & Cancel button.. I thought it would be simple but i haven't figured it out yet. :s any help would me more than appreciated!

```
$('.ask_email').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var email = prompt('Your account details will be sent to        this e-mail:','');
if(email)
    document.location = this.href + '&email=' + escape(email);
return(false);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well you can not add text into windows promt..but you can use custom promt which is developed in jQuery...http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prompt is a browser dialog, you can not add anything to it.

```
var email = prompt("Please enter you email");
```

will result in var email getting the entered value in the prompt dialog.

if you want to have a rich dialog which content you can modify, just use jQuery UserInterface Dialog. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Great! thanks to both of you guys! i wish i had the knowledge to use any of those 2 resources you gave me but i don't.. :(
Thanks anyways! now i know i can't so at least i will not waste any more time on this! :)

Comment: just check the source code from the dialog examples. they are really very simple ;) and please accept my answer.

Comment: i checked the source code/s but i don't know which of their examples would work best for my needs..

Comment: i think that you need a dialog with a form inside it. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form